# Should taxpayers be allowed to vote where their taxpayer dollars go?

Tags: taxes

I am pondering over the pros and cons of having taxpayers submit via popular vote which federal executive departments or agencies they want their tax dollars to be allocated towards. This would appear to be in accordance with democracy but I'm still debating it.

Comment: Is this not just a specific case of "Is direct democracy better than representative democracy"?

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally don't answer questions about what politicians *should* do, because answers to such questions are just personal opinion. For more information on what kind of questions do and do not belong on this website, please check out the articles [What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on the [help center]()

Comment: Let's imagine that for a second: no taxpayer wants to fund the IRS, either because they're planning to cheat or simply because it's not sexy. A few years later, the IRS is severely under-funded so most people don't feel the need to pay their taxes since they can't be caught. Conclusion: the federal government is bankrupt because people stop paying taxes, game over.

Comment: Some taxpayers might want to fund the IRS to ensure that other people pay their taxes (people are spiteful), but probably not enough.

Comment: @user253751 “People are spiteful” Some, perhaps. But some people would vote for it to be funded because good governance is important?

Answer (score 11):

## No.

There are questions where a direct "yes or no" vote is appropriate. Do you want stem cell research or not? Do you want capital punishment or not? Those questions can be clearly answered.

There are other questions which are not "yes or no" but rather "how much" or "what percentage." Like how to split the budget.

*"Do you want low taxes?" "Yes, of course."*
*"Do you want public debt?" "No, of course not."*
*"Do you want decent infrastructure?" "Yes, of course."*
*"How shall we reconcile that?" "Let the politicians figure that one out."*

Consider the Brexit mess. There was a slim majority for Brexit, but no majority for any one type of Brexit. They might have tried to negotiate a deal first and then vote on it, but Article 50 didn't work that way.

Comment: Those earlier questions are more nuanced as well. You can have capital punishment in some cases but not in others, you can allow some methods of capital punishment but not others, etc. The same goes for stem cell research, how much money do you want to spend on it, what rules govern what researchers can do? All these questions yield to more nuanced questions.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica There is a clear yes/no question about capital punishment. No means no capital punishment of any kind for any crime. In most Western European countries this is the law and a large majority of the population shares this view, so this is not something hypothetical. The proponents of capital punishment don't agree with each other on the details but that is a followup question on the binary yes/no. The same principle applies to stem cell research, the no camp is just a universal no, no matter the details.

Comment: @quarague You might find (hypothetically) that a majority of people are for capital punishment, but a majority are against lethal injection, a majority are against beheading, a majority are against execution, and a majority are against electrocution.

Comment: @quarague by that logic the Brexit referendum is also an appropriate "yes or no" vote. After all, it's only difficult when people vote in favor of it. Realistically though, that makes the referendum moot. If you are sure that one option will win, then it's a waste of money to hold the referendum. If you're not sure, then you need to prepare for dealing with both outcomes and that's where it gets tricky.